# Just struggling with this Regex expression, need to make it more specific

Tags: regex

My source string is:

```
[irc:st:sp][irc:tl:ad,sp]
```

I just want to match against any one group between the bracket and my current, and incomplete, match pattern is:

```
\[irc:tl:.*sp\]
```

This would return true

Because my match pattern is not correct and fires across bracketed groups then the following is also true

```
[irc:tl:ad][irc:st:sp]
```

ie [irc:tl*sp] is the summary of the above as far as my current match pattern is concerned so is true.

How can I make my pattern more specific to apply only within an on set of brackets, so

```
[irc:st:sp][irc:tl:ad,sp] \\ true

[irc:tl:ad][irc:st:sp] \\false
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicitly forbid brackets: `\[irc:tl:[^]]*sp\]` - `[^...]` says "any character except these"; if you have a closing bracket in the set, it needs to be first. Escaping is not required or desired.

Comment: Huge thanks for this. The first one worked for me as it forbade crossing the bracket boundaries, whereas the second one did not since the match crosses over the brackets, and returned true due to [irc:tl*sp] where * has cross over brackets.

Comment: Ah, right. Yeah, not the case for second technique; they're often able to be used interchangeably, but not here. I'll edit to reflect this.